# JSON Unicode Characters not displaying correctly with AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, unicode, ng-bind-html

I am receiving this json array and using angular to display it.

Shorted example:

```
        $scope.results = [{"description": "\u003ca href=\"http://google.com \" target=\"_blank\"\u003eClick Here\u003c/a\u003e"}];
```

The problem is that the value contains html code or unicode characters that don't work properly.

I've searched and tried ng-bind-html with no luck.

In the html source code I get this:

```
&lt;a href="http://google.com " target="_blank"&gt;Click Here&lt;/a&gt
```

Instead of this:

```
 <a href="http://google.com " target="_blank">Click Here</a>
```

[Here is an example Plunker with my problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/5KCTOideVoHI7LIeNaHV?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ng-bind-html` and then we could get the trusted Html in anchor tag rendered on the page.

**Markup**

```
<span ng-repeat="result in results" 
 ng-bind-html="result.description | unsafe">
</span>
```

[**Plunkr Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/UwoeeAmqctZuVoHg65Q3?p=preview)